# How to Compute the Lattice Spectrum

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, phonons

How precisely would one compute the lattice spectrum $D(\nu)\,d\nu$? Referencing Ziman's `Theory of Solids', it is simply a matter of solving the equations of motion and counting the number of $\nu_q$ values that fall into each $\,d\nu$

However, if you solve this, you get a continuous solution, such as $\nu_q = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{m}2\sin(\frac{q a}{2})}$. How would one use this to count states for the lattice spectrum?